# How to filter JSON data in itemBuilder

Tags: json, dart, flutter

So I have a JSON url with some data like name, latitude and longitude. However, not every object has a latitude and longitude and I only want to display the names of the objects that do have the latitude and longitude.

JSON example object with lat and lng:

```
    dynamicDataUrl: "http://example.com",
    staticDataUrl: "http://example.com",
    limitedAccess: false,
    locationForDisplay: {
        coordinatesType: "LA4556",
        latitude: 52.2490470982696,
        longitude: 6.16317987442017
    },
    identifier: "4556random2595",
    name: "Los Angelos"
    },
```

JSON example object without lat and lng:

```
    dynamicDataUrl: 
"http://example.com",
    staticDataUrl: "https://example.com",
    limitedAccess: false,
    identifier: "1234randomi1233",
    name: "New York"
},
```

```
List data;
Future<String> theRequest() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    });

    setState(() {

      var getRequestedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data = getRequestedData['parkingFacilities'];

    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.theRequest();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool notNull = false;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Parking Spots'),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
          if( data[i]['locationForDisplay'] != null ) {
            return new ListTile(
              title:  new Text(data[i]['name']), 
              trailing: new Icon(
                saved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: saved ? Colors.red : null,
              ),
              onTap: (){_save(data[i]['name'], data[i]['locationForDisplay']['latitude'], data[i]['locationForDisplay']['longitude']);},
            );
          }
        },
      )
    );
  }
```

The code I have tried inside of the itemBuilder only displays one object name. I have also tried to already filter in inside of the `setState()` function, using a forloop, which does give me back the data I need when I print it (only the object names from objects WITH a lat and lng), but when I try to set the `data[i]['name']` inside as the title of a ListTile, I still see ALL of the names.

How can I properly filter the JSON, so that only the names are displayed of objects that DO have a lat and lng?

Comment: This is because you are `return`ing on the first object that has a "locationForDisplay" instead of filtering out objects and returning the filtered List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `List` variable and filter the values, like this:

```
  List data;
  List<Map> filteredList;


  Future<String> theRequest() async {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      });

      setState(() {

        var getRequestedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        data = getRequestedData['parkingFacilities'];

        filteredList = List();
        for(item in data){
          if (item['locationForDisplay'] != null && item['locationForDisplay']['latitude'] != null && item['locationForDisplay']['longitude'] != null
          ) {
            filteredList.add(item);
          }
        }

      });
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      this.theRequest();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      bool notNull = false;
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Parking Spots'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: filteredList == null ? 0 : filteredList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
              return new ListTile(
                title:  new Text(filteredList[i]['name']), 
                trailing: new Icon(
                  saved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: saved ? Colors.red : null,
                ),
                onTap: (){_save(filteredList[i]['name'], filteredList[i]['locationForDisplay']['latitude'], filteredList[i]['locationForDisplay']['longitude']);},
              );

          },
        )
      );
    }
```

Comment: adding `filteredData == null ? 0 : filteredData.length` to itemCount, resolved this issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`data` is presumably a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, so you could add:

```
  data = getRequestedData['parkingFacilities'];
  data.removeWhere((m) => m['locationForDisplay'] == null);
```

Comment: `data` was of type `List`, but I changed that to `List<Map<String, dynamic>> data` and pasted the new line and it's now giving me this exception: `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'`

Comment: Just remove the type from the predicate, and leave data as a `List` - see updated answer